# Trying to understand the use of が as の

Tags: particle-の, particle-が, possession

Many times I come across sentences that uses が instead of の to indicate possessiveness.

Example:
彼**が**車　instead of　彼**の**車.

The dictionary says that が can also "indicate possessive (esp. in literary expressions)", but why not to use の?

This confuses me a lot. Is there a nuance using が or の to possessiveness?

Comment: Can you give us a complete sentence as an example?

Comment: I can't remember or find a complete sentence right now, the only thing I remember in those sentences was that they were using が as a の, if the whole sentence is read the understood sense of the が in it is possessiveness.

Comment: Then we can't tell from your question which of the following is true: ① You misunderstood. ② You encountered a lexicalized possessive like 我が, and mistakenly generalized it to include examples like 彼が. ③ You encountered an older form of the language. ④ You encountered a dialect like [熊本弁](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%86%8A%E6%9C%AC%E5%BC%81#.E7.89.B9.E5.BE.B4) which still has possessive が outside of fossilized forms.

Comment: ① It's not impossible. ② What would be other examples of "lexicalized possessives"? ③ The text I read was recent. ④ Probably.

Comment: It seems most likely that you misunderstood. What is the rest of the sentence?

Comment: Sorry for not giving a example sentence, I don't remember where I found those. When I come across such sentence, I'll edit my question including it.  =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a question of possession.

I'll show it to you using your example.

Let's say : He has built a car.

彼が車を造りました。

If you want to say more about the car e.g.’ The car he built got famous in the whole country.’, it comes to the change your question is about. The sentence will be like this.
彼の造った車が、全国で有名になりました。

Comment: Well, I think the sentences I saw were similar to your first example, like with the same pattern. Probably those sentences were like this, because if I read it without interpreting that the subject is 彼 instead of 車, it's erroneously interpreted as possession. Thanks! =D